# X-Cart stopped working, it seems like it goes somewhere and never comes back

Tags: php, session, x-cart

I am facing a very strange issue in X-Cart, I am working on localhost. It was working fine and now it is not working anymore. It shows nothing but a blank page, it seems like it goes somewhere and then doesn't come back.

We installed another X-Cart on localhost and it worked fine. I am just doing theming, client will purchase license. So is it because of some sort of licensing problem? That it works for some time and then stops working?

I tried to debug and seems like problem is in `sessions.php` file in include directory. It seems like statement creating problem is `x_session_start()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your seeing a blank page it's probably because there's been an error and you have error reporting disabled.

You can enable it by putting this code on the first line of the script...

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: yes actual problem was very minor and was predictable after just showing errors. Database tables were actually corrupted.